# How to make the last element break out of a flex?

Tags: html, css

I cannot change the HTML of the code below, so I need some help with the CSS. There are three elements of the dropdown and *Add to Cart* and information all next to each other. But I really don't want the information to be next to the *Add to Cart* button, or to be part of the inline flex. How can I get it to be displayed where it was before the flex (which is below the *Add to Cart* button), but still keep the dropdown and *Add to Cart* next to each other?

[image]

```html
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
  <div class="quantity">
    <select name="quantity">
      <option value="1" selected="”>1</option></select>
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to Cart</button>
        
        <span class="wc-points-rewards-product-message wc-points-rewards-product-variation-message "><span class="wc-points-rewards-product-message "><span></span>Earn up to <strong>25</strong> points with this purchase | <span></span>60-Day Money-Back Guarantee</span></span>
        </div>
```

```css
.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.wc-points-rewards-product-message {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's not complete. Share you css code

Comment: By the way, from formatting your HTML code, I noticed that the `selected` attribute of the `option` element has one normal quote and one smart quote `"”` instead of two normal quotes `""`. This will prevent your HTML from rendering properly, so make sure to fix that in your actual website.

Comment: @NatRiddle Yeah sorry that's because I was cutting the amount of code in the question. The actual HTML is actually correct, will sort this in the question